# How change centre of raotation GO in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

My object has a daughter who needs to revolve around his parent, but for some reason the center of rotation moves away, from which the rotation is not quite right. Where the mouse is located the center of rotation

[image]

Comment: you can customize the pivot but please tell your problem more briefly

Comment: how are you making it rotate around it? quickest way to change a pivot point is to make an empty game object either as parent to that which will be your point, or a child it actually doesnt matter you just use that to rotate around

Comment: I made an empty object but it did not produce results

Comment: set pivot by click on gameobject (to which you are trying to make pivot) and then click on https://answers.unity.com/storage/attachments/134124-unity-pivot-tool-handle.png

Comment: @ArtemVolkov sadly we cant see what you do, if you make the empty object, place it where you want to be the pivot and use that, it does work - if thats not working unfortunately it means you did something wrong, there are a number of examples on youtube